# Regex to find all the words except those which are between special characters

Tags: python, regex, string

I am currently learning regex in python and got stuck at a problem in which I have to separate the string such that there are words that are not between any ( ) or [ ].

Let me show an example:

String: `Ann Arbor (University of Michigan)[1]`

Output: `Ann Arbor`

Comment: please let us know how you attempted to solve the problem (simple working code example)

Comment: Yes, I tried. Being a noob in the regex, I was unable to solve the problem. I am practicing to get better at it. I am stuck at this problem for a few hours that is why I decided to look for the solution online but couldn't find any.

Comment: I actually solved the problem without regex But the solution requires specifically a regex expression. That is why I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach uses re.sub to remove anything in brackets and the brackets that surround them.

```
import re

string = 'Ann Arbor (University of Michigan)[1]'
print(re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", string))
```